# Set jwplayer 6.7 control bar to bottom : width issue with player control

Tags: jwplayer, video-player, jwplayer6

Is it possible to stop showing the jwplayer control bar on hover and bring it to bottom, Since often times control bar is overlaying the subtitles and it is not clearly visible

for example - if I want to reduce player volume and still want to see the video subtitle, but control bar hides subtitle and I can not view the video

Is this possible in jwplayer 6.7 ?

Same question can be found here in [JWPLAYER forum](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/6460284-jwplayer-control-bar-bottom-in-6-7?new=6460284),

Here is a JSfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2YNG/15/)  `http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2YNG/15/`

As answered in the forum, making change in xml file can help

```
<component name="controlbar">
            <settings>
                <setting name="margin" value="-30"/>
                <setting name="fontcase" value="normal"/>
                <setting name="fontcolor" value="0xFFFFFF"/>
                <setting name="fontsize" value="11"/>
                <setting name="fontweight" value="normal"/>
                <setting name="maxwidth" value="800"/>
            </settings>
```

But I have faced problem that player control width is too much and it is going out of the player width, I tried changing "maxwidth" but it is not coming correctly. how to solve this width issue?

[image: jwplayer bottom control width issue]

I don't want it to exceed the player width but player control width and player width should be same.

Another issue which i faced was, when I have made jwplayer `primary : flash` jwplayer control is totally hidden when negetive margin is set (-30).

```
<setting name="margin" value="-10"/>
```

[image: jwcontrol hides -- > primary flash]

Sorry I can not share the jsfiddle link, when changed to `primary : flash` skin file is showing crossdomain error. If I change again to HTML5 it works fine

[HTML5](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2YNG/24/): http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2YNG/24/

[FLASH](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2YNG/18/): http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/M2YNG/18/

where should i make change in xml file

Comment: In JW6, it will always hide, sorry.

Comment: do you mean it will hide in flash?, it will always hide?I didn`t understand ? ....I thought I am really close to solving this, is there no around for this ?... can you please explain little bit ....

Comment: In JW6, the controls always will be in an over state, and fade/hide. There is no way to set controlbar to bottom in JW6.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , but changing margin in xml file worked I thought that could be good solution for both flash and html5 but in flash, jwplayer controls are hiding... :(

Comment: Yes, it will change the margin, but it will still always hide regardless, sorry.

Comment: hmmmm I just wish there was some work around for this. I have been trying for long..... Thanks for reply anyway...

Comment: No problem, any time.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer : jwplayer vs 5 support this feature `controlbar:bottom` when passed in setup, why was this feature stopped in jwplayer 6 ?

Comment: The skinning model for JW6 does not lend itself well to support controls in any option other than over.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer we've been talking with Heatherann and Dick Dawson there at JW Player regarding integration of the JW Player into an enterprise app. I just now came across this hurdle of 'always showing the controlbar'. We're using version 6.9, is there no way to ensure the control is always visible?? Has/Will that change in the future? Can it be changed with a custom skin? Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to change this I'm afraid.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer, this seems like a pretty major oversight/short-coming! In our application we are using specifically placed Captions (meta data) which will never collide with the control bar.. and in our app, it's pertinent that it remains visible while in a playback or paused state. You're saying that there is no way to force the controlbar to show, at all times?????

Comment: You are right, that is what I am saying.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer, i am having same issue, and i want to know is there any way i can reinitialize jwplayer after this line run "jwplayer().getRenderingMode()" so code will be like this if (jwplayer().getRenderingMode() == html5 ){ jwplayer("myElement").setup({skin: "jwplayer/six.xml"})} else { jwplayer("myElement").setup({skin: "jwplayer/five.xml"})}. is this possible

Comment: You should be able to do this, do you have a link?